# I have a CNAME for www, how do I redirect root domain there?

Tags: dns, cname

My DNS setup is rather simple: a CNAME for `www`, default (registrar's) nameservers for the root.

Now I want to redirect from the root domain to www, which I thought would be a simple task, but it's not working.

I've followed every guide out there on how to change the `htaccess` file and my registrar is even offering a simple setting to do this as well, but no result. When I go to the root of my domain in a browser it *instantly* says:

> mydomain.com's server DNS address could not be found.

What's the right course of action here? Should I add a server alias? A domain alias? Should I add some records to my DNS settings? I'm out of ideas.

Note: I do not have a static IP address for my server. Rather, I need to direct requests to my server using a `CNAME` record.

Comment: And your `www` subdomain works OK? What does your CNAME record say? How long has it been since the DNS has been configured? If you are within the first 48 hours then the domain could still be propagating around the world's DNS servers.

Comment: @DocRoot Yeah, works perfectly. My CNAME says www. Configured it a week ago.

Comment: "My CNAME says www." - I'm not sure that I follow? It seems you already have an answer to your problem, but I'm curious as to what your CNAME record actually _points to_ (the _value_ of the CNAME record; "www." is effectively the _name_)? (A CNAME record is simply an alias that points to the canonical domain.) Ordinarily a `CNAME` record for `www` points to the bare domain eg. `example.com` (the canonical domain) for which an `A` record points to the IP address. A CNAME record by itself is not "normally" sufficient; but you say this works OK??

Comment: @DocRoot PaaS provider (Galaxy for Meteor).

Comment: Ah yes, I see your problem now. As mentioned in comments below, you will need another server (or service) to which to point an `A` record to (for the "bare" domain) so you can manage the HTTP redirection. There is additional information on the Meteor.com website: [Redirecting the root domain](http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/dns.html#root-domain-redirect)

Comment: @DocRoot Thanks. I thought those links were just describing standard methods to redirect, never realized it was more involved than that!

Comment: @Yeats As I've mentioned before, this is why it is important to truly learn about the technologies in use. You don't need to become a DNS expert, but it would do you well now, and in the future to learn about what role DNS plays, what the purposes of various record types are, etc, and how the DNS works together with your web server and application to deliver content.

Comment: @EEAA Sadly, there exists literally no good explanations/guides on DNS.

Comment: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/mobile/9780596100575.do

Comment: @EEAA I fell asleep from the cover alone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need an `A` record for your domain root, pointing to the IP address of your server.

Only once you have that in place (thus directing requests for `example.com` to your server) will your `.htaccess` rules take effect.

---

Since your server does not have a static IP address, you will need to find out if your DNS provider supports `ALIAS` or `ANAME` records. These allow you to have `CNAME`-like functionality at the zone apex. If your provider does not support these records types, you should be able to move to a provider that *does* support them without significant effort.

Comment: I have a CNAME. My server doesn't have a static IP address.

Comment: That would be helpful information to include in your question, as it changes things significantly.

Comment: I said exactly how things were. I have a CNAME for `www` and nothing else.

Comment: The fact that you use a `CNAME` for www does not preclude you having a static IP for your server. I'm just saying - this is helpful information to include.

Comment: Don't know what `ALIAS` or `ANAME` records are or what to do with them even if they do support them. Are you saying it's impossible to have a redirect without an A record or one of those things?

Comment: Anyway, I edited my answer to reflect your current situation.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that this is impossible. You cannot have a `CNAME` at your domain apex (example.com). Also, redirects are a function of HTTP, not DNS. You need *both* pieces in place to do what you want - you need DNS records that direct clients to the correct server, and then on the server, you need an HTTP redirect to redirect requests from example.com to www.example.com.

Comment: Can't I just use any old server for the root A record since it's gonna be redirected to the real site anyway?

Comment: Sure, that would be fine. Then you're managing another server, though, and if that server goes down, requests to example.com will fail.

Comment: Don't I do that anyway? I mean, the `htaccess` file has to *be* somewhere, right? I can edit it now through my registrar, so supposedly it's on some server somewhere that is very different from my real host.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information on how you have things set up for me to answer that.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question, but it's funny that you can't answer that without more information, as though `htaccess` files *can* float magically out in space somewhere. Why do I need an A record pointing somewhere before the `htaccess` rules take effect? Presumably you mean that the A record has to point at the server where the `htaccess` file is located, no? (Real question, not rhetorical).

Comment: " Why do I need an A record pointing somewhere before the htaccess rules take effect?" Because how else will request from your clients reach the server that is hosting your apache/htaccess? Requests need to get there *somehow*, and that somehow is via DNS records (either an A record, if you can point to a static IP or ALIAS/ANAME if you need CNAME-like functionality).

Comment: Exactly. So the A record has to point to where the `htaccess` file is located. Good, okay.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I feel like CloudFront's "CNAME flattening" could be used here?

Comment: @v0idless Yes, absolutely. That is another (arguably more standards-compliant) way to get CNAME-like functionality at he zone apex.

Comment: @EEAA +1 because the whole ANAME/ALIAS thing can be quite confusing (in part for lack of a standard) and your answer is very clear. I'm surprised by the lack of support for ANAME/ALIAS coming from registrars… With the growth of Heroku and similar services I would expect demand to be high. People end up having to pay for DNS services they used to get for free from their registrars.